# Error connection pod logstash and elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, minikube

for days I've been having this problem between connecting logstash and elastic in kubernetes, I'm using minikube.
These are the logs from the logstash pod:

> [2023-11-20T10:16:01,269][WARN ][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::HostUnreachableError, :message=>"Elasticsearch Unreachable: [http://elasticsearch:9200/][Manticore::ClientProtocolException] elasticsearch:9200 failed to respond"}
>
> [2023-11-20T10:16:01,303][ERROR][logstash.licensechecker.licensereader] Unable to retrieve license information from license server {:message=>"No Available connections"}
>
> [2023-11-20T10:16:05,280][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"https://elastic:xxxxxx@elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'https://elasticsearch:9200/'"}

These from elastic:

> {"@timestamp":"2023-11-20T10:11:36.006Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -Djava.security.manager=allow, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j2.formatMsgNoLookups=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-11862069038782619862, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms1902m, -Xmx1902m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=997195776, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"main","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.node.Node","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-57dc5fc6f7-42zzd","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
> {"@timestamp":"2023-11-20T10:16:31.425Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"received plaintext http traffic on an https channel, closing connection Netty4HttpChannel{localAddress=/10.244.0.15:9200, remoteAddress=/10.244.0.16:47910}", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-57dc5fc6f7-42zzd][transport_worker][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.netty4.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"f_RDyR5xRwyVLO9IugQkZw","elasticsearch.node.id":"ZUGoJReVReixqtOnRe6LOg","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-57dc5fc6f7-42zzd","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}
>
> {"@timestamp":"2023-11-20T10:16:36.319Z", "log.level": "INFO", "message":"Authentication of [elastic] was terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user [elastic]", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsearch.server","process.thread.name":"elasticsearch[elasticsearch-57dc5fc6f7-42zzd][system_critical_read][T#1]","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.RealmsAuthenticator","elasticsearch.cluster.uuid":"f_RDyR5xRwyVLO9IugQkZw","elasticsearch.node.id":"ZUGoJReVReixqtOnRe6LOg","elasticsearch.node.name":"elasticsearch-57dc5fc6f7-42zzd","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster"}

This is my configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.11.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200      

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  namespace: logging
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9200
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9200
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-config
  namespace: logging
data:
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }

    output {
      elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "https://elasticsearch:9200" ]
        ssl => true
        ssl_certificate_verification => false
        user => "elastic"
        password => "mypass"
      }
    }
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash
  namespace: logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: logstash
          image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:8.8.0
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5044
          volumeMounts:
            - name: pipeline-volume
              mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
              subPath: logstash.conf

      volumes:
        - name: pipeline-volume
          configMap:
            name: logstash-config
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: logstash
  namespace: logging
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5044
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 5044
  selector:
    app: logstash
```

To get the elastic password I follow these steps:

```bash
oc exec -it elasticsearch-57dc5fc6f7-42zzd -- bash

elasticsearch@elasticsearch-57dc5fc6f7-42zzd:~$ bin/elasticsearch-reset-password -u elastic -a

WARNING: Owner of file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/users] used to be [root], but now is [elasticsearch]

WARNING: Owner of file [/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/users_roles] used to be [root], but now is [elasticsearch]

This tool will reset the password of the [elastic] user to an autogenerated value.

The password will be printed in the console.

Please confirm that you would like to continue [y/N] y

Password for the [elastic] user successfully reset.

New value: mypass
```

Can someone help me?

I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logs you provided, it seems like there are two main issues:

1. Logstash is trying to connect to Elasticsearch using **HTTP** but
   Elasticsearch is expecting **HTTPS** connections. This is indicated by
   the log message "received plaintext http traffic on an https
   channel, closing connection". (I assume it's logstash)
2. The authentication of the user 'elastic' is failing. This is
   indicated by the log message "Authentication of [elastic] was
   terminated by realm [reserved] - failed to authenticate user
   [elastic]".

To address this issue start with, ssh into logstash pod and run the following command:

```
curl -ks "https://elasticsearch:9200" -u elastic:mypass
```

Note: `ssl_certificate_verification` is depreceated use [ssl_verification_mode](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-ssl_verification_mode) instead.

Comment: I solved it by overwriting the logstash.yml file that is generated when the pod was created, so I made a configmap, I added to the configmap:
logstash.yml: |
   xpack.monitoring.enabled: false

This is because, if it was enabled as default it pointed to http and not https, I think it was linked to the fact that mine was a free version

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and happy to hear it's solved. `xpack.monitoring.enabled` false as default. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring-internal-collection-legacy.html#monitoring-general-settings-legacy

I think another settings that you changed fixed the problem.